# I want to create a API endpoint to fetch User and User Profile by attribute "user_id" in djangoRestAPI, user_id will be sent by the client

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

**models.py**

```
class User_profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    profileImg = models.ImageField(upload_to='User/Profile_Picture', default='User/Profile_Picture/logo.png')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default=None)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default=None)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=False)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    privacy = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PRIVACY_CHOICES, default='public', blank=False)
    requests = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='follow_request_user', default=None, blank=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
    following_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='following_user', default=None, blank=True)

    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='user_followers', default=None, blank=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User_profile
        fields = "__all__"
```

**api_views.py
**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializer import *
from .models import *


class ProfileAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=kwargs['user_id'])
        profile_serializer = ProfileSerializer(user,many=True)
        return Response(profile_serializer.data)
```

**api_urls.py
**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import api_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/<user_id>', api_views.ProfileAPI.as_view(), name="profile")


]
```

I want my response in JSON format so that i can use it in android app. I went through many blogs and Stackoverflow answers but any of that didn't give desired output

In Short i just expect that client sends a userid and get User and UserProfile in json format

getting "TypeError: 'User' object is not iterable" as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want solution to your code just remove `many=True` from ProfileSerializer.

`many=True` is passed, when we pass list of model objects to serializer, and we want response in form of LIST.

---

### ***And this is more concise implementation for above usecase***

**api_views.py**

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView
from .serializer import *
from .models import *

class ProfileAPI(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = User_profile.objects.all()
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/<int:pk>', api_views.ProfileAPI.as_view(), name="profile")

]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve your code a lot. Anyway, in order to get the user simply remove `many=True` from ProfileSerializer.

Comment: okay done ... but getting this error. "AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `ProfileSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'name'.
"

Comment: You are passing a user instance to ProfileSerializer. What you can do is create UserSerializer and pass the user instance to it or instead of fetching user from User table fetch user profile from User_profile table and pass that instance to ProfileSerializer.